# Prove or disprove: $a_n >0$, $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n)$ is convergent $\Rightarrow$ $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

We know that $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n)$ is convergent if $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent where $a_n >0$ for all $n\geq 1$. This follows by using the inequality $\ln(1+x) \leq x$ for all $x\geq 0$ and the comparison test. I am trying to see if the converse is true, i.e., whether the convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n)$ implies the convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$.

Comment: for $  0 < x < 1$   we also have $\log(1+x) > x - \frac{x^2}{2}.$

Comment: @WillJagy : This example doesn't answer my question.

Comment: What do you mean by converse? Can you state it precisely in the main body of the question? The title is not the converse in the logical sense.

Comment: Let the known facts ≕ $Γ=[γ_1∧γ_2∧...∧γ_]$, with initial claim ≕ $γ_1$: $$□[∀ ⟮∊ℕ_1 ∧ _∊ℝ_+⟯﹕∃\lim ∘( \sum_{=1}^∞⟮_⟯)]⇒[∀⟮∊ℕ_1 ∧ _∊ℝ_+⟯﹕∃\lim ∘( \sum_{=1}^∞⟮\ln (_+1)⟯)]$$ ⟹ $$∀ ⟮_∊ℝ_+⟯﹕□[∃\lim ∘(\sum_{=1}^∞⟮_⟯) ⇒ ∃\lim ∘( \sum_{=1}^∞⟮\ln (_+1)⟯)].$$          $$\text{null-hypothesis} (_0):  [〈⇒,⟹〉_{γ_1} ⊭ 〈⇐,⟸〉_{γ_1}].$$                        $$\text{alternative hypothesis} (_1):  [_0⊶⊥] → [〈⇒,⟹〉_{γ_1} ⊨ 〈⇐,⟸〉_{γ_1}].$$ (cont'd..)

Comment: (..cont'd) Per [jjagmath's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4351372/946772) (computation and LCT, which could be taken as $(γ_2 ∧ γ_3) ⋤Γ$), $〈⇔,⟺〉_{γ_1}⊶⊤$;   $∴ _1$ is true     [where $⊶⊥$ and $⊶⊤$ means “ is false” and “ is true”, respectively; used with qualification of necessitation($□\cdot$) above, thus corresponding to stronger invalidity and validity; likewise $_1$ corresponds to affirmative of the original query: Yes, the converse of $γ_1$ is also true].

Answer (score 6):

We have $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = 1$$
This implies, under the assumption $a_n>0$, that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+a_n)$$ converges if and only if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges, by the [Limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Comment: Yes, I just saw this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria

Comment: Fixed, thank you

Comment: @Gary: yes, indeed. Just keeping him honest! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the estimate
$$\exp( \log (1+a_1) + \cdots + \log(1+a_n))=(1+a_1) \cdots (1+a_n) \ge 1 + (a_1 + \cdots + a_n)$$

Comment: What is the source of said equality and inequality?

Comment: First equality follows from the properties of $\log$, the inequality is Bernoulli's, or just expand the product.